# Problem while installing SP solution "Timeout error CodePlex.SharePointInstaller.InstallException: Timeout error"

Tags: 2013, central-administration, solution-package, installation, configuration

I am trying to install SP solution inside my SharePoint 2013, but during the installation i got the following exception :-

```
***** Bamboo Core V2 (Prerequisite Component) *****
***** ERROR *****
Timeout error
CodePlex.SharePointInstaller.InstallException: Timeout error ---> CodePlex.SharePointInstaller.InstallException: Timeout error
   at CodePlex.SharePointInstaller.InstallProcessControl.WaitForJobCompletionCommand.Execute()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at CodePlex.SharePointInstaller.InstallProcessControl.WaitForJobCompletionCommand.Execute()
   at CodePlex.SharePointInstaller.InstallProcessControl.TimerEventInstall(Object myObject, EventArgs myEventArgs)
[17/04/2015 02:12:18] The Solution was not removed. Make sure all jobs against the solution are executed.

***** Bamboo SharePoint Wiki Publisher *****
***** ERROR *****
Timeout error
CodePlex.SharePointInstaller.InstallException: Timeout error ---> CodePlex.SharePointInstaller.InstallException: Timeout error
   at CodePlex.SharePointInstaller.InstallProcessControl.WaitForJobCompletionCommand.Execute()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at CodePlex.SharePointInstaller.InstallProcessControl.WaitForJobCompletionCommand.Execute()
   at CodePlex.SharePointInstaller.InstallProcessControl.TimerEventInstall(Object myObject, EventArgs myEventArgs)
[17/04/2015 02:27:38] The Solution was not removed. Make sure all jobs against the solution are executed.
```

so can anyone advice on what could be causing this timeout error ? baring in mind that i am running the installation using the admin account.

Comment: how many servers in the farm, usually this happen when one of the server is not responding properly. Make sure SharePoint Time and Admin services is running on all servers.

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE thanks for the reply, now i have the SharePoint +sql on the same server it is a single server ,, and when i check the services both the admin and SP timer is working well .. can u adivce please ?

Comment: when you trying to install it, whats about the Server resources i.e ram, cpu? did you disable the loopback check and also do you internet access on server?

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE i have 10 GB of RAM and CPU utilization will be around 70-00% during installation ,, and yes i have set the DisableLoopbackCheck in the registry.. so can u adivce further please ?